# Moving files after inserting them into Database

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a folder that I am fetching xml file contents from and inserting them into a database. The challenge that I have is to move files from original destination to another destination which in this case works as a backup storage.

I am getting an error that says

> Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo::getClientOriginalName()

In my controller I have used

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo;
```

Below is my code I am using to fetch file contents and inserting them into database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$directory = storage_path('app/xmlentries/uploads'); //Folder I am getting file contents from

$files = File::allFiles($directory);

foreach($files as $file) {

$contents = $file->getContents();

foreach((array) $contents as $content)
{
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($content);

$data = [
'experience' => $simpleXml->ExportData->Requisition->EssentialFunction,
'job_requirements' => $simpleXml->ExportData->Requisition->EssentialFunction,               
];

Vacancy::insert($data);
}
}

$destinationPath = storage_path('app/xmlentries/processed');

$request->file($file->getClientOriginalName())->move($destinationPath);
```

Please note that the inserting of file contents to database works fine. How would i get the filename of the files that I can use to move the files around to the new destination

Answer (score 0):

From [Laravel recipes](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/134/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location):

```
if (!File::move($oldfile, $newfile))
{
    die("Couldn't rename file");
}
```